# Retrieve Azure function trigger info

Tags: logging, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Is there way to retrieve Azure function trigger info (like service bus topic name) from execution context? I was trying to create generic **LogError** function that can be used in different azure functions like in example below:

```
[FunctionName("azureFunctionName")]
public static async Task RunNormal(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(topicName: "events-topic", subscriptionName: "events-processmanager-sub", 
        Connection = "processManagers_Listen_SERVICEBUS")]
    string eventMessage,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        //... do some work here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogError(log, e)
        throw;
    }
}

private static void LogError(ILogger log, Exception e) 
{
    // **** somehow find topic and subscription from the context here ?? ****
    var topicName = ...
    var subscriptionName = ...

    log.LogCritical(e, "Failed to process message from {topic}/{subscription}", topicName, subscriptionName);
}
```

Comment: The topic name is known. It's defined on the Function. What specific info do you want to get from the `ExecutionContext`?

Comment: Topic name is known for particular function. But I want to implement common error logger that will capture function input in general for any. I couldn't find how to get it from ExcutionContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that would allow you to get to the attribute and from the attribute get all the required information:

```cs
static class TriggerDiscoverer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to derive the required configuration information from the Azure Function and trigger attributes via reflection.
    /// </summary>
    public static TTriggerAttribute TryGet<TTriggerAttribute>() where TTriggerAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var frames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
        foreach (var stackFrame in frames)
        {
            var method = stackFrame.GetMethod();
            var functionAttribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<FunctionNameAttribute>(false);
            if (functionAttribute != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in method.GetParameters())
                {
                    var triggerConfiguration = parameter.GetCustomAttribute<TTriggerAttribute>(false);
                    if (triggerConfiguration != null)
                    {
                        return triggerConfiguration;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

For a Service Bus triggered function it would be called in the following way:

```cs
var attribute = TriggerDiscoverer.TryGet<ServiceBusTriggerAttribute>();
```

and to access all the information:

```cs
attribute.QueueName
attribute.TopicName
attribute.SubscriptionName
attribute.Connection
```